# Move a zoomed image in a div to see another part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am actually displaying an object (a camera feed).
The goal is to zoom and then move my feed as I would do with a GMAP item.
I tried GMAP ImageTiler but it didn't really worked as expected.
I then tried to do it myself, but I'm also interested by another way (a better/cleaner way) to do what I'm actualy doing!

```js
$("#videoContainer").css('height', 480);
    $("#videoContainer").css('width', 640);

    $('#videoContainer').on('mousewheel', function (event) {
        var height = $('#stream').height();
        var width = $('#stream').width();

        if (height == 480 && width == 640 && event.deltaY > 0) {
        } else {
            if (event.deltaY > 0) {
                height /= 2;
                width /= 2;
                $("#stream").css('height', height);
                $("#stream").css('width', width);
                console.log(height, width);
            }
            else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
                height *= 2;
                width *= 2;
                $("#stream").css('height', height);
                $("#stream").css('width', width);
                console.log(height, width);
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="videoContainer" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <img id="stream" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to this code, I am able to display the feed and zoom it in a pretty tribal way.
Once zoomed (thanks to JQuery Mousewheel, GitHub link at the end of the post), I can only see the top left fourth of the feed by hiding what is overflowed.
The last step is, thanks to a system drag and drop-like, moving the feed with the mouse (or a pinch if using a phone).

The fact is that I'm unable to do it.
Any idea how to do this anyone ?
Thanks :)

Mousewheel : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution for my problem.
There are things that must be corrected, but we have zoom (pinch or mouse scroll) and drag the video feed.

Here's my code.

```js
$("#videoContainer").css('height', $('#stream').height());
    $("#videoContainer").css('width', $('#stream').width());

    $('#videoContainer').on('mousewheel', function (event) {
        var height = $('#stream').height();
        var width = $('#stream').width();

        if (height == 480 && width == 640 && event.deltaY > 0) {
        } else {
            if (event.deltaY > 0) {
                height /= 2;
                width /= 2;
                $("#stream").css('height', height);
                $("#stream").css('width', width);
            }
            else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
                height *= 2;
                width *= 2;
                $("#stream").css('height', height);
                $("#stream").css('width', width);
            }
        }
    });

    function startDrag(e) {
        if (!e) {
            var e = window.event;
        }

        var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

        if (targ.className !== 'dragme') {
            return
        }
        offsetX = e.clientX;
        offsetY = e.clientY;

        if (!targ.style.left) {
            targ.style.left = '0px'
        }
        if (!targ.style.top) {
            targ.style.top = '0px'
        }
        coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
        coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
        drag = true;

        document.onmousemove = dragDiv;
        return false;
    }
    function dragDiv(e) {
        if (!drag) {
            return
        }
        if (!e) {
            var e = window.event
        }
        var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
        // move div element
        targ.style.left = coordX + e.clientX - offsetX + 'px';
        targ.style.top = coordY + e.clientY - offsetY + 'px';
        return false;
    }
    function stopDrag() {
        drag = false;
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        document.onmousedown = startDrag;
        document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
    }
```

```css
.dragme{
    position:relative;
    width: 270px;
    height: 203px;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="videoContainer" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <img id="stream" class="dragme" alt="Camera is loading"
         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help somebody.